# iOS Share to Mail app always shows text at the top and image at the bottom instead of following content in array

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to share content from my app to Mail. In particular I'd like to have:

- some text at the top
- image in the middle
- some text at the bottom

However it seems all my text is getting pushed to the top and image ends at the bottom. What am I doing wrong and how can I accomplish this order?

I'm currently sharing

```swift
let content: [Any] = ["Top text", UIImage(systemName: "pencil")!, "Bottom Text"]
```

and get the following result, which is not what I want.

[image]

This is the code I'm using.

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum Coordinator {
    static func topViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController? = nil) -> UIViewController? {
        let vc = viewController ?? UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController
        if let navigationController = vc as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(navigationController.topViewController)
        } else if let tabBarController = vc as? UITabBarController {
            return tabBarController.presentedViewController != nil ? topViewController(tabBarController.presentedViewController) : topViewController(tabBarController.selectedViewController)
            
        } else if let presentedViewController = vc?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(presentedViewController)
        }
        return vc
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    func share() {
        let content: [Any] = ["Top text", UIImage(systemName: "pencil")!, "Bottom Text"]
        
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: content, applicationActivities: nil)
        let viewController = Coordinator.topViewController()
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = viewController?.view
        activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
        }
        
        viewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: share) {
            Text("Share")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```